# How can I create a RW-Everything script to disable C-states in my Intel i5-2320 Processor?

Tags: cpu

My Intel i5-2320 Processor whines when it is in an idle state due to the [Piezoelectric Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectricity).  I have read I can disable the C states (clock stopped) feature of the processor to fix this.  However, my OEM BIOS has locked me out from disabling this feature.  Due to this, I need help creating a script in [RW-Everything](http://rweverything.phpnet.us/index.htm) that can run when Windows loads to turn this feature off.

Comment: Messing with that kind of tool has some seriously scary effects if done wrong. **If someone's suggestion fails, super user isn't responsible for your broken hardware**

Comment: Precisely. I've also never heard of a computer whining due to the piezo effect - there's quite a few louder noises in the average computer. This is a rather scary question in so many ways

Comment: @Journeyman Geek I found out what is was from superuser.com, reference: http://superuser.com/questions/121883/any-way-to-disable-specific-cpu-idle-cx-states

Comment: @Simon - This ringing noise is already making this junk.  I paid the price for an OEM machine.

Comment: Then you should call and return it to the OEM

Comment: @Simon I already called Lenovo and they told me I "just have to deal with it".

Comment: and because they told me that, I filed a complaint with the BBB.

Comment: No takers?  I can sign a liability waiver if needed...