# ASUS M5A97 UEFI BIOS - Where the heck are the C-State settings?

Tags: uefi, power-management

I've been getting coil whine since switching to a new PSU, and I'm worried about power stepping affecting my SSD RAID0 performance, so I did some reading and decided I needed to disable some C-States.

I've been pouring over my motherboard's manual and online literature, and I cannot figure out what I need to change or where it is.

The CPU configuration panel in the advanced settings just has three options, and the only one that seems relevant is `Cool'n'Quiet`.

Is there anywhere I can change C-States in this UEFI program, or am I limited to disabling `Cool'n'Quiet`?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/121883/any-way-to-disable-specific-cpu-idle-cx-states/897989#897989