# Why is this computer hissing and not powering on?

Tags: windows, cpu

I work in IT and I'm having this issue with a few of the PCs in my realm.

They won't power on at all, fans don't spin up, no beeps of any kind. But when the PSUs are plugged in, they hiss. Faintly, but audibly. It's not the PSUs, I already changed those out.

PC 1:

Intel DG35EC, CPU is probably a Core 2 Duo but the sticker is missing and I'm too lazy to go in and look.

PC 2:

Intel DG35EC, Core 2 Duo.

Looking at the specs, I'm thinking there's a fault with the 35EC?

Comment: What series of events led up to this occurring? Since it is more than one there is some common factor here, unless coincidence puts their deaths at the same time with the same conditions.

Comment: If you're too lazy to have a look inside it's probably best you look for another job. What else have you checked? You've swapped the PSU out but have you stripped the machines back to basics. Have you checked the power switch is connected properly.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams They're both in student libraries, but at different schools. I don't really know what's been going on with them because there's too many PCs in our district to monitor like that.

Comment: Some of the Core2 Duo CPUs were infamous for making noise while in the C3 idle state.  See http://cpunoise.shrtl.com/pmwiki.php?n=Main.FAQ and perhaps http://superuser.com/questions/121883/any-way-to-disable-specific-cpu-idle-cx-states and let us know if those seem to fit what you're running into.

Comment: @techie007 Not related. That happens when the PC is on. These two won't turn on.

Comment: @Cubie | If you don't have a starting point then swap these computers out and get to work on troubleshooting. Strip them to the bare bones and add components till they work. If they don't work at all your board is probably finished.

Comment: Well then, as other have suggested, you'l lahve to get your hands on them and (gasp) do some more physical troubleshooting. ;)  Check the MB for expanded caps, and blown voltage controllers amongst other things.  Really though, just do the usual, strip it down to CPU/MB/PSU, work up from there.

Comment: @Cubie | It has already been pointed out, but allow me to be very clear. We here provide answers to people who want to help themselves. If you are to lazy to simply search basic information, do you see any reason the rest of us should sit here and provide answers. That attitude will not get you anywhere in the digital world where we all like to learn and develop. Just a kind note for you to consider.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No beeps indicates there's something wrong with the motherboard. If you have a spare compatible motherboard, try exchanging it to see if it works. Claiming you're too lazy to do rudimentary investigations is an excuse which gets you fired or at least warned in most companies.

Comment: Well, OR, one of the required power supply connectors isn't connected, OR the CPU isn't seated properly, OR (sometimes) no memory installed, OR the CPU fan isn't connected ... there are a number of reasons that a system won't start even with the PS connected, and not enough of the required steps done to generate beep codes.